# how do you insert null values into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

In sql server enterprise manager, how do you write an insert statement and pass in `null` values?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO atable (x,y,z) VALUES ( NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Answer (score 64):

If you're using SSMS (or old school Enterprise Manager) to edit the table directly, press CTRL+0 to add a null.

Comment: Excellent - I always forget this!