# How to insert null values to a Uniqueidentifier Column

Tags: c#, .net

In my C# project I need to insert some null values to a UniqueIdentifier column.

For fields city Guid, state Guid fields I should be able to insert null values 
if there is no value(uniqueidentifier) available.
I am getting the following error

"Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

here is my code.

```
   string Query = @"INSERT INTO mytable
                            (table_GUID,
                            Date,
                            city_GUID,
                            state_GUID,                            
                            ) 

                        VALUES
                        ('" + tableGUID + @"', 
                        '" + Date + @"',  
                        '" + cityGUID + @"',
                        '" + stateGUID + @"'
                    )                       

 string insert = sql.executeNonQuery(Query);
```

Comment: First things first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Are the GUID object actual GUIDs in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not supply the values like this. Create a SqlCommand and supply the values as parameters. To insert null values, use `DBNull.Value`

```
    var command = new SqlCommand(
        @"INSERT INTO mytable (table_GUID, Date, city_GUID, state_GUID)                      
          VALUES (@TableGuid, @Date, @CityGuid, @StateGuid)", sqlConnection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TableGuid", tableGUID ?? DBNull.Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", Date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CityGuid", cityGUID ?? DBNull.Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StateGuid", stateGUID ?? DBNull.Value);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Another way to do this would be to supply NULL as a value. See [how do you insert null values into sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149665/how-do-you-insert-null-values-into-sql-server)

You could also define a helper function to return either the value wrapped in quotes or a NULL string.

```
private string GetQuotedParameterThing(Guid? value)
{
    return value == null ? "NULL" : "\"+ value + \"";
}
```

Then just supply `GetQuotedParameterThing(tableGUID)` to your command string.

Comment: the problem is these are not always null. if there is no value then I should insert null. if there is a value then I should insert the Guid with single quotes. How can I insert null without single quotes in the above method? The single quotes are causing the issue here

Comment: See my edit. You can use the null-coalescing operator to supply DBNull.Value if the parameter is null.

Comment: thank you for your reply, But I I dont have access to sqlCommand. sqlCommand is in another class.Is it possible can you show your example in the format I am using? appreciate your help

Comment: @Henry you should use `SqlCommand`, otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injection. Simply put, you are writing bad code. Don't do it. If you don't have access to it you need to gain access to it. Refactor the code. It's as simple as that.

Comment: "then I should insert the Guid with single quotes" - no, you should not. `uniqueidentifiers` are not strings - thinking of them as strings is perhaps a large part of the problem here. Malvin is entirely correct to suggest passing them as ADO.NET parameters - and ADO.NET parameters can express `null` values via `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 1):

An answer already exists showing how to do this with ADO.NET parameters, which is a perfectly correct answer to this issue. If you have to use raw TSQL, then you will need to distinguish between null / non-null values; the non-null values will require quotes, but the null values will need to be sent as `null` - no quotes. `null` is a perfectly valid nullable uniqueidentifier - but `'null'` *is not*.

However, in your example I suspect the real trick would be to change your `sql.executeNonQuery` method to **accept parameters**. If you do not : then I guarantee you that your current system **is fundamentally broken**. Right now. It is dangerous. A problem. Risky.

But this is easily fixed; in your case, *ridiculously* easily; for example, this could be:

```
const string Query = @"
INSERT INTO mytable (table_GUID, Date, city_GUID, state_GUID) 
VALUES (@tableGUID, @Date, @cityGUID, @stateGUID)";

string insert = sql.executeNonQuery(
    Query, new { tableGUID, Date, cityGUID, stateGUID });
              ^^^ hot damn! who knew parameterization could be that easy!?
```

if you simply make your existing `executeNonQuery` method something like:

```
void executeNonQuery(string query, object args = null) {
    //... not shown: your code that gets a connection
    connection.Execute(query, args);
    //... not shown: your code that cleans up
}
```

by just adding a reference to [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper); simply, dapper makes correct parameterization a breeze; the above change could be made *without impacting any of your existing code*, except by allowing it to be parameterized in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem may have been that your code allowed "empty strings" to make it through. Maybe you could check for string.Empty and then pass in  Guid.Empty  or NULL instead.